# Using pdf-reader gem in RoR to display PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I'm new to Ruby and using MVC for web apps so I was wondering where I would put the example code [from the gem documentation](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader). For my app, I'm using Paperclip to upload a PDF file and I want to display the PDF in the view. I tried putting the code in the controller like so:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'

class BooksController < ApplicationController 
...
  def index
    io     = open('http://www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf')
    reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
    puts reader.info
  end
```

but when I run this, it freezes the server. I'm wondering how would I get this PDF to show in the view and also how I could test output with the console. For example, with the code above, where can I see the output of the "puts reader.info" statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try, this one:

```
io     = open('http://www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf')
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)

reader.pages.each do |page|
  puts page.fonts
  puts page.text
  puts page.raw_content
end
```

According to the documentation, If you need to access the full program for rendering a page, use the `walk` method of `PDF::Reader::Page`

```
class RedGreenBlue
  def set_rgb_color_for_nonstroking(r, g, b)
    puts "R: #{r}, G: #{g}, B: #{b}"
  end
end

io       = open('http://www.cbu.edu.zm/downloads/pdf-sample.pdf')
reader   = PDF::Reader.new(io)
page     = reader.page(1)
receiver = RedGreenBlue.new
page.walk(receiver)
```

Comment: put the code where you want to access pdf. From your above code put in the index method

Comment: One more thing, if you just want to show the pdf, don't use pdf-reader gem. In that case I strongly recommend to do it `send_data` method. Let me know, if your purpose is to just show the pdf, I will share the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using Active Storage for PDF uploads, it's got better documentation, easier implementation and it's well integrated into rails from version 5.2.2.

Enabling Active Storage in your application starts with a Rake task: running

```
rails active_storage:install
```

Once executed, it creates two tables that Active Storage needs to deliver on its promises: **active_storage_attachments** and **active_storage_blobs**.

Here is a link to the official documentation:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d3893ec38ec61282c2598b01a298124356d6b35a/activestorage/README.md

That's all.

**I hope this helps**